# Low contrast segmentation of circles

Tags: image-processing, matlab, grayscale, image-segmentation

I have some problems in Matlab with the segmentation of circles in this image. The contrast difference is really really small and the image itself is really noisy. I did some processing on the image and increased the contrast difference but still I dont know how to do next.

I found [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0141635912001432) but I dont know how to proceed with background reconstruction using DCT. I did previous steps though.

Image before adjustment:

[image: Image before adjustment]

Image after adjustment (the innercircle is cut from the whole figure using imfindcircles):

[image: Image after adjustment]

Each spoke consist of 3 circles and there are 10 spokes so 30 circles in Total.

---

What I've tried so far:

```
clc
clear
im = imread('f8.jpg');
im = mat2gray(im);

im = 1 - im;
s = size(im);

%contrast enhancement method suggested in paper
for x = 1:s(1);
    for y=1:s(2);
        a = max(im(x, :)) / mean(im(x, :));
        a;
        b = max(im(:, y)) / mean(im(:, y));
        b;
        ab = (a+b)/2;
        im(x, y) = im(x, y) * ab;
        im(x, y);
    end 
end

imshow(im);

%bluring

h = fspecial('average', [2,2]);
im= filter2(h, im);

%find circles
[c, r] = imfindcircles(im, [35 50], 'Sensitivity', 0.92, 'Edge', 0.01);

% figure(1) 
% imshow(im)
% hold on
% viscircles(c, r, 'EdgeColor', 'b');
% hold off

% making mask that cuts out the inenr circles

mask = bsxfun(@plus, ((1:256) - c(1,1)).^2, (transpose(1:256) - c(1,2)).^2) < r(1)^2;
mask = im2double(mask);
mask_al

for x=1:256
    for y=1:256
        if mask(x, y) == 1;
            mask(x, y) = im(x, y);
        end
    end
end
```

**To sum up**:

I need to count how many circles are visible on the image.

Comment: My code is here -http://paste.org/71029

Answer (score 0):

If you have some user seed input available (even if unavailable, you can use a Hough circles to seed) you might want to consider Active Contours:

> Kass, Michael, Andrew Witkin, and Demetri Terzopoulos. "Snakes: Active contour models." International journal of computer vision 1.4 (1988): 321-331.

Comment: I tried Hough Circles, actually this is how I am getting the inner one. For smaller ones it is not working correctly. I will look at active contours for sure. Thx for replying!

Comment: There are many implementations of snakes available already. B-snakes would best fit your problem. Try that first.

Answer (score 0):

Use imfindcircles from Image Processing Toolbox. You can also try the function  activecontour . See help doc for more info on these.